# Open tab from the icon clicked - chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My background-min.js

```
var openTab = function () {
  chrome.tabs.create({url: 'index.html'}, function (tab) {
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.removeListener(openTab)
  })
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(openTab)
```

and this is my manifest.json

```
"background": {
        "scripts": ["scripts/background-min.js"]
  },
"permissions": ["background"],
"chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "index.html"
  },
```

I can open the new tab from the icon clicked only when the new tab is open (extension is running). When my extension is completely in the background the icon click won't work.

Comment: Why are you removing listener each time tab was created?

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise the tab will open 2,3,4x times after the first close.